# How to implement dependency object/property on custom class?

Tags: wpf, object, dependencies

Here is my Person Class:

```
    public class Person
{
    private string _lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }

    }
}//close class
```

Here is my XAML:

```
        <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" 
                 Height="50" Width="300"
                 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=PersonObject}" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />

        <Button Height="50" Width="100" x:Name="btnChangeValue" Content="Change Value" Click="btnChangeValue_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is my XAML.CS

```
public partial class ClassDependency : Window
{
    public Person objPerson = new Person();
    public ClassDependency()
    {
        objPerson.LastName = "testing...";
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public Person PersonObject
    {
        get { return objPerson; }
        set { objPerson = value; }
    }

    private void btnChangeValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        objPerson.LastName = "New value after click....";
    }
}//close class
```

My question is: After clicking "btnChangeValue" it does changing Last Name in my code behind but it is not reflection my textbox "txtLastName". How can I fix this??? Should I implement Dependency Property in my xaml.cs file?? I tried that too but no use.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PersonObject", typeof(object), typeof(ClassDependency));
    public Person PersonObject
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonObjectProperty, value); }
    }
```

What should I do?? Please advice..

Comment: Further explanation: you will see _this in my TextBox binding. _this is my current window name <Window x:Name="_this">. When I run my window. I see "Testing" on my text box but on clicking button it doesn't change value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set 
        { 
            _lastName = value; 
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the framework gets notified when the property changes. See [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: Do I still need to implement DependencyProperty in my Xaml.cs file? Or only modifying my class the way you told me should work?

Comment: This modification should be enough. You don't need a dependency property.

Comment: When I type "if(PropertyChanged!=null)" visual studio unable to recorgnize PropertyChanged word? I can see PropertyChangeCallBack, PropertyChangedEventArgs, PropertyChangedEventHandler and lots of other but unable to see just "PropertyChanged" in my intellisense dropdown. THanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the event definition. Add this: `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are not raising the PropertyChanged event, so the UI is not aware of the value change, on the setter of your dependency properties raise the PropertyChanged event as shown below:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    private string _lastName; 

    public string LastName 
    { 
        get { return _lastName; } 
        set  
        {  
            _lastName = value;  
            if (PropertyChanged != null) 
            { 
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName")); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do I still need to implement DependencyProperty in my Xaml.cs file? Or only modifying my class the way you told me should work?

Comment: You just need to update your class, no changes need to be done on your xaml.cs file. As long as the values is binding from your object no other thing is required.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. When I type "if(PropertyChanged!=null)" visual studio unable to recorgnize PropertyChanged word? I can see PropertyChangeCallBack, PropertyChangedEventArgs, PropertyChangedEventHandler and lots of other but unable to see just "PropertyChanged" in my intellisense dropdown. THanks

Comment: Don't forget to add the event definition in your code. 
`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`